# Android use usb as uart serial port

Tags: android

Can anybody tell me how to create android apps that send character via usb port as uart communication? I have looked at android.hardware.usb in developer guide but it is not mentioned.

Comment: This article says some devices support it via the headphone jack: https://www.pentestpartners.com/blog/how-to-hardware-hack-android-over-uart/

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at this project?

http://code.google.com/p/android-serialport-api/wiki/android_to_rs232_guideline

Comment: Have you looked here: http://code.google.com/p/android-serialport-api/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fandroid-serialport-api%2Fproject%2Fjni%253Fstate%253Dclosed